# How to create dynamic object with key-value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Input Data

```
var rows = [{
   'type':'action',
   'key':'active_session',
   'count': 4596
},{
   'type':'action',
   'key':'active_session',
   'count': 100
},{
  'type':'action',
  'key':'know_more',
  'count': 100
},{
  'type':"category",
 'key': "reactions",
 'count': 500
}];
```

Expected output

```
 {"action": {
        "active_session": 4696,
         "know_more":100
    },
 "category":{
     "reaction": 500 
  }
 }
```

I have input data, don't know how to achieve expected output in the easiest way. Please help I will be very thankful.

Comment: you should use lodash for such heroic tasks :)

Comment: he has added 4596 + 100 = 4696

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the desired result using `reduce` method and use an object as accumulator value.

```js
var rows = [{"type":"action","key":"active_session","count":4596},{"type":"action","key":"active_session","count":100},{"type":"action","key":"know_more","count":100},{"type":"category","key":"reactions","count":500}]

const result = rows.reduce((r, { type, key, count }) => {
  r[type] = r[type] || {}
  r[type][key] = r[type][key] || 0
  r[type][key] += count
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```